# Insert into a MS Access query built from two tables in a MySQL backend with a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, sql, odbc

We have a MS Access frontend connected to a MySQL backend via ODBC. We are trying to move two tables, with a one-to-one relationship between them, into the backend. We then have an Access query to combine the tables with an INNER JOIN and display the query as a datasheet on a form.

When the tables are in Access (not linked), you can add a row in the query datasheet view, and Access creates a row in both tables with the same primary key. When the tables are moved to the MySQL backend, attempting to insert a new record into the query is prevented with an error in the statusbar:

```
Cannot add record(s); primary key for table `Child` not in recordset.
```

Here are the simplified table and query definitions:

```
-- MySQL table definitions:
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Model varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Child (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ModelNum int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Child_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Parent (ID)
);

-- MS Access Query:
SELECT Parent.ID, Parent.Model, Child.ModleNum
FROM Parent INNER JOIN Child ON Parent.ID = Child.ID;
```

Access will let you add a row to the query if you only enter data for the Parent table (ie, Model). This of course only creates a row in the Parent table. When you try to type anything in the ModelNum field, Access prevents it and displays the above error message in the statusbar.

I've tried creating the relationship in the Access Relationships window. I've added TIMESTAMP columns to both tables. I've also used wireshark to sniff the MySQL connection; Access doesn't appear to send anything when it shows the error.

Is it possible to get Access to do the right thing? It should send an `INSERT INTO Parent`, get the ID then `INSERT INTO Child` with that key. I can add a button and do it in VBA, but in our real app there are many related tables and places where the functionality would have to be duplicated. We can user a trigger to create the Child rows, but that isn't appropriate in all situations in the real application.

We are using MS Access 2007 and MariaDB 5.5.37. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know it's been a while since you asked this question, but thought I'd give my two cents.  I think what you would look to do here is set up a Pass Through Query to do the heavy lifting, wrap both INSERTs in a transaction, then execute the code via VBA.  Here is a quick proof of concept.

Create a Pass Through query in your Access db, with a connection string that has the proper credentials to perform the inserts.  I am not a MYSQL guy, but from my research, the following SQL should be OK:

```
BEGIN;

DECLARE @ID INT;

INSERT Parent(Model)
VALUES('~Parent_Model');

SET @ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT Child(ID, ModelNum)
VALUES(@ID, ~Child_ModelNum);

COMMIT;
```

You should run this code (replacing ~Parent_Model and ~Child_ModelNum with some values for testing) in your native MYSQL enviornment to make sure that piece of code is working.  What it is doing is adding a record to Parent, getting the last automatically added ID number (for the session) and storing it in @ID, then using that value to insert into the Child table.  Save this query in your db as qryInsert.

Now here is some code to execute the query:

```
Public Sub InsertTest(Parent_Model As String, Child_ModelNum As Integer)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strOriginalSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryInsert")

    strOriginalSQL = qdf.SQL

    qdf.SQL = Replace(qdf.SQL, "~Parent_Model", Parent_Model)
    qdf.SQL = Replace(qdf.SQL, "~Child_ModelNum", Child_ModelNum)

    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    qdf.Execute

ExitMe:
    qdf.SQL = strOriginalSQL
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    GoTo ExitMe

End Sub
```

The code is accessing the query you made earlier, replacing ~Parent_Model and ~Child_ModelNum with the parameters passed in (parameters with pass through queries are a bit wonky, so I just did it this way to show the concept), then executing the code against the MYSQL db.  In production, you would have to watch out for all the normal gotchas with dynamic SQL, of course.  Also, with the SQL property of QueryDefs, it changes and saves when you assign in, so you would need to keep the original SQL somehow (you can create the whole QueryDef in code, connection string and all in code, even).  You can work out the best way to do this for yourself.

To run the code, I added a quick wrapper with some test values:

```
Public Sub RunInsertTest()
    Call InsertTest("From Access", 1232)
End Sub
```

If you step into the code and follow it all the way through, you should have the records added to both tables, with the same IDs.  You can leverge the code however you see fit in your app.  Again, just a proof of concept and you could implement in many ways; maybe your pass through query exectues a stored procedure and passes it parameters.  Whatever the case, I think this provides a decent solution to your needs, and should be releavant to your whole app.  Hope that helps.